# Mapping root in web.xml [weblogic]

Tags: java, mapping, weblogic, web.xml

Hi I have a context and i have a mapping problem with this context. When I put this to my web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I can only access like this.

> http://domain.com/sub-context/

but I wanna access like this

> http://domain.com/sub-context

what should I do?

Edit: I saw that when i hit for http://domain.com/sub-context in browser it redirects me to http://domain.com/sub-context/ although i havent do anything special for that. Who is doing this. Weblogic?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RedirectFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/sub-context</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Then in RedirectFilter:

```
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain filterChain)
  throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)resp;
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    String redirectURL = "http://domain.com/sub-context/";
    response.setHeader("Location", redirectURL);
  }
```

Adapted from here: [redirect through web.xml in google-app-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563455/redirect-through-web-xml-in-google-app-engine)

Comment: I think I am misunderstood. I have a sub-context(has its own war and a a web.xml in it).